# How is it that Peremo = Per + Emo?

Tags: etymology

According to several different Latin dictionaries, including Lewis & Short, the word [peremo](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dperimo) (to destroy) has the etymology of being the combination of PER + EMO. However, I thought *emo* meant to buy or purchase, so I don't see how this is a root word for peremo which seems to mean something totally different.

Answer (score 10):

While *emō* normally means "buy", the ancestral meaning seems to have been something like "take". Compare the Proto-Slavic cognate **ę-ti* "take, acquire", or the distant Latin relative *pōmus* "fruit" (the first part is cognate with Greek *apo*: fruit is "something taken off/away from" the tree). And indeed, this is the meaning we see in most prefixed forms: *adimō* "deprive", *dēmō* "remove".

So the original meaning of *perimō* seems to have been something like "take away thoroughly and completely"—that is, "cause to vanish". And indeed, in Classical times this still seems to be its most common meaning: Cicero in *De Divinatione*, for example, describes how the full moon was *subitō perempta est* (i.e. eclipsed). But from there, "cause to vanish" poetically meaning "kill, destroy" is an easy step.